# How to enter the paramter for batch file using PHP?

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

I have this file batch (test.bat), that contains these

```
javac c:\Hello.java
```

I can run this batch file using PHP ..

```
<?php
system("cmd /c C:\\test.bat");
?>
```

but I want to enter the name of java file from PHP code how can I send this parameter to batch file,, what is the required modifications in batch file and php code ?

Comment: Why you don't bypass the scrippt and call the java compiler directly?

Comment: That doesn't make much sense :?

Comment: Of course, it did :) , thnaks

Comment: You posted the content of the batch file above. How can you don't know it? (Thats the point, that seems illogical to me ;)).

Comment: I mean this command :)     exec("javac c:\Hello.java");

Answer (score 1):

will work:

```
  <?php
    exec("javac c:\Hello.java");
  ?>
```

Comment: after the command string, you can pass a variable (e.g $output that will be an array), if the script return something, each output line will be added to this variable, after you need just interate into this array to view tha output

Comment: can I use cd command with exec ... such as    exec("cd c:\\test\\".$projectName);

Comment: `cd` is an internal command, you need to invoke it `cmd /c cd ..`